# Assigning cumulative Nth day over a datetime period. [i.e. this row belongs to 134th day]

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have an **example** Series as follows:

```
     TimeStamp
0    1/1/2019
1    1/1/2019
.       .
.       .
.       .
500 31/1/2019
501  1/2/2019
502  2/2/2019
503  2/2/2019
```

How would I go about achieving the following:

```
     TimeStamp   Nth Day
0    1/1/2019      1
1    1/1/2019      1
.       .          .
.       .          .
.       .          .
500 31/1/2019     31
501  1/2/2019     32
502  2/2/2019     33
503  2/2/2019     33
```

We are not just finding out the number of days passed between two timestamps but also assigning Nth day to the relevant row.

I have written a For Loop that checks if there is a switch on TimeStamp.dt.day like this: last iteration was over 31 and this one is over 1 [as moving from 31st jan to 1st feb], so this means this is a new day. If new day, then append +1nth day to a new Series created as a result of this loop.

It works, however, I have half a million entries and this takes a long time (15-20 min). Is there an efficient way to do this?

Edit: The loop. Forgive the verbose old/new vars.

```
daySeries = df['TimeStamp'].dt.day

dayList = pd.Series([1])

for eachday in daySeries:

    new = eachday   

    if len(dayList) == 1:        
        old = new

    lastVal = dayList[-1:].values[0]

    if new == old:
        dayList = dayList.append(pd.Series([lastVal]), ignore_index=True)
    else:
        dayList= dayList.append(pd.Series([lastVal+1]), ignore_index=True)    
    old = eachday    

df['Nth Day'] = dayList
```

Comment: check out `pd.factorize`

Comment: can you post the for loop code

Comment: @ksooklall please check edited question

Comment: What do you want to get in 'Nth Day' column? Is it number of days from the first date or is it a order number of different dates in Timestamp column? For example if first values in timestamp are 1/1/2019, 3/1/2019, 7/1/2019 what should be the values of 'Nth Day'? 1,2,3 or 1,3,7?

Comment: @Stepan I see now I should have been clearer in choosing example starting form 1st Jan. Given any timeperiod, I want days to begin from 1 i.e. 1,2,3 as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Series is called `df`, you can use the following approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['Nth day'] = 0
df.loc[df['TimeStamp'] != df['TimeStamp'].shift(),'Nth day'] = 1
df['Nth day'] = df['Nth day'].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Here you can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-label) to get column with "new value indicator" (1 if value is new and 0 if not). Then you can get cumulative sum of this indicator using [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

Comment: Brilliant! It's almost instant now. Btw, what was so inefficient about the for-loop vs this method? Something to do with array operations being efficient? [Forgive me I am beginner on programming].

Comment: I'm afraid I can't provide any details, but I know that pandas is optimized for array operations and for..loop over elements is the most inefficient way to do with arrays in pandas. You can read something like this for example: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06

Comment: @Stephan No problem, I wanted some direction for self-study and the link is helpful. Thanks!